# Recursive Checksumming

Tags: command-line, checksums

I've been using the following command line to do recursive checksumming of directories. It seems to get the job done, but still being a newbie I've been wondering, are there any potential problems with doing it this way? Is it possible for this command to miss files or otherwise mess up?

```
find ./dir/ -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; > files.sha1
```

Comment: You could use `+` instead of `\;`. That way multiple files are passed to `sha1sum` instead of starting a new `sha1sum` for each file. Otherwise it looks good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong I can see with your approach. You're excluding directories and  find will include hidden files by default. Yeah, it's fine.

But I'll offer you an alternative because that's what I do:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
sha1sum **
```

`globstar` enables a recursive match for `**` and `dotglob` enables matching hidden files. Between them they expand to all the filenames and sha1sum can parse them all.

The main problem with this approach is it will pass *all* the filenames off to `sha1sum` in one fat pile. While this can be somewhat faster at small loads, it will explode if you have too many filenames. I don't know what the cut-off is.

Comment: The cutoff is `ARG_MAX`, the size of a command's arguments,, you can get the value for your system with `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score -1):

#### Python script with hashlib and os.walk

Aside from using `find` and `globstar`, python has modules for hashsum calculation and recursive walk through directory tree. Thus, one can write a simple script just as presented below. In fact, this script is pretty much the same as what I've used for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/932699/295286) with one minor difference.

This script assumes that you want to recursively walk through the current working directory, so make sure you `cd` to the desired top directory first.

I would also recommend that you save it in `~/bin` directory and run `source ~/.bashrc` prior to usage, since that way, you can just type the name of the script on command-line.

The script gathers all files, including the hidden-ones ( with the leading dot in the filename ).

#### Script Source

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from hashlib import sha1

def get_sha1sum(file_path):
    sha1sum = sha1()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fd:
        data_chunk = fd.read(1024)
        while data_chunk:
              sha1sum.update(data_chunk)
              data_chunk = fd.read(1024)
    return str(sha1sum.hexdigest())

def find_files(treeroot):
    for dir,subdirs,files in os.walk(treeroot):
         for f in files: 
             full_path = os.path.join(dir,f)
             path_sha1sum = get_sha1sum( full_path  )
             print(path_sha1sum,full_path)

def main():
    find_files('.')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

#### Demo Run

```
bash-4.3$ cd Wallpapers/
bash-4.3$ recursive_checksum.py 
c66af072272d2c516e29832d0a86afa0e8e61d8c ./moon_moon.jpg
37829801c48ea0420414fc78de45adb13e4b117f ./wat.png
6cc3dd2541d00aa5fb8fd6ec703d3c7653ce4708 ./hard_drive_wallpapers/hard-drive.jpg
52fbff84cba6bbbfadc5777c1189ec39aef9176a ./hard_drive_wallpapers/hard-drive5.jpg
5bfe52eb8b31f50dc7bd1b1991dcc1d7260ec65e ./hard_drive_wallpapers/hard-drive4.jpg
f2f85eaa24c8c5b82bbedd55f887ea5fc520ac21 ./hard_drive_wallpapers/hard-drive3.jpg
bcdcf278c176fa93557627a33bedebe4e508e27a ./hard_drive_wallpapers/hard-drive2.jpg
```